# Getting an "process suspension ios 12 unable tp acquire assertion for process with pid 0" error in my ionic 3 IOS app

Tags: ios, ionic3, wkwebview

I am build an ionic 3 app. I am using WKWebView 4.0.1 version. The app works fine in Android, however the app crashes after few minutes when I run the IOS version. I get the following error message when the app crashes:

> process suspension ios 12 unable to acquire assertion for the process with
>   pid 0

The app usually crashes when I switch between pages that contain google geojson maps. My ios version is 12.3.1. It seems many people have this issue and many points to the fact that the app is taking up lots of memory. I am completely lost on this now. Please help me through this.